# What does the value in @RestController annotation do?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

Creating a simple `Spring Boot` application using `Maven`. I have given a value with `RestController` annotation, but it doesn't work. If I don't use the `RestController`'s value, it works. I want to know, why it's not working and What's the use of value in `@RestController`?

`http://localhost:9090/app/hello` this gives error

`http://localhost:9090/hello` this works fine

`@RestController("/app")` What's the purpose of `"/app"` this value inside `@RestController` annotation?

P.S: I know, I can use `@RequestMapping("/app")` on ScraperResource class.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

```
@RestController("/app")
public class ScraperResource {
    @GetMapping("hello")
    public String testController() {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
server.port=9090
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is because the "/app" inside your RestController has **nothing to do with your URL mapping**, but rather with a **"logical component" name** being used internally Spring.

You should do this instead, if you want to prefix all your controller methods with /app (or just leave it out).

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/app")
public class ScraperResource {

    @GetMapping("hello")
    public String testController() {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

Without @RestController Spring won't know that this class should handle HTTP calls, so it is a needed annotation.

Answer (score 2):

As per the Java Doc associated with the `@RestController` annotation, this is the meaning of the value that you are passing to it:

```
/**
     * The value may indicate a suggestion for a logical component name,
     * to be turned into a Spring bean in case of an autodetected component.
     * @return the suggested component name, if any (or empty String otherwise)
     * @since 4.0.1
     */
    @AliasFor(annotation = Controller.class)
    String value() default "";
```

As such, it does not influence or affect what URL your endpoint is accessible with. If you want to add a top-level mapping you can use the `@RequestMapping("/app")` on the class-level as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter in the `@Controller` annotation allows you to name the Controller. In cases where there are multiple beans of the same type, the bean name can be used along with the `@Qualifier` annotation to let Spring know which component to inject during autowiring.

From the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-scanning-name-generator):

> When a component is autodetected as part of the scanning process, its
> bean name is generated by the BeanNameGenerator strategy known to that
> scanner. By default, any Spring stereotype annotation (@Component,
> @Repository, @Service, and @Controller) that contains a name value
> thereby provides that name to the corresponding bean definition.
>
> If such an annotation contains no name value or for any other detected
> component (such as those discovered by custom filters), the default
> bean name generator returns the uncapitalized non-qualified class
> name.

Read more about autowire disambiguation, and how to use the component name with `@Qualifier` [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-autowire#disambiguation).

> By default, Spring resolves @Autowired entries by type. If more than
> one bean of the same type is available in the container, the framework
> will throw a fatal exception.
>
> To resolve this conflict, we need to tell Spring explicitly which bean
> we want to inject.
>
> When there are multiple beans of the same type, it's a good idea
> to use @Qualifier to avoid ambiguity.
>
> Please note that the value of the @Qualifier annotation matches with
> the name declared in the @Component annotation of our FooFormatter
> implementation.